# Blogger template - Inserting code with a specific URL

Tags: templates, url, blogger

Blogger template - Inserting code with a specific URL.

I want to put specific meta-titles in a blogger blog. The meta-descriptions I put in the "description search" but the titles I want to manually put. I want it to be a different name than the title of the post.

I followed the instructions here to make the "if/else" conditions: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=es

I got a code something like this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
    **<title>Motivation</title>**
<b:elseif cond='data:blog.url == "http://www.xxxx1.com"'>
    <title>Motivation2</title>
**<b:elseif cond='data:blog.url == "http://www.xxxx2.com"'>**
    <title>Motivation3</title>
<b:else/>
    <title>~~~~<data:blog.pageName/>~~ <data:blog.title/></title>
</b:if>
```

But this condition is not working

```
<b:elseif cond='data:blog.url == "http://www.xxxx1.com"'>
```

I tested with something like this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "http://www.xxxx1.com"'> 
<title>testing32</title>
</b:if>
```

and is not working either.

To prove that the data:blog.url is working I put a code like:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
    **<title><data:blog.url/></title>**
</b:if>
```

And it shows my URL perfectly....

The only way I found to make it work is by filter by the name of the post.

```
<b:else cond='data:blog.**pageName** == "motivation"'>
```

yes, is tedious but if the title has " **'** " or " **"** " or extrange characters blogger not get the code right.

Answer (score 0):

Each entry of your blog have an ID number. You have to use it in order to do a correct filter per post.
Then you can use basic conditional structures like this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.postId == &quot;1234567890&quot;'>
    <title>Your custom title for post with ID 1234567890</title>
<b:else/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.postId == &quot;0987654321&quot;'>
        <title>Your custom title for post with ID 0987654321</title>
    </b:if>
<b:else/>
    <!--Default title-->
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
</b:if>
```

You can get the postid editing each post and looking at the URL in the Blogger editor, or checking the source code of your post entry searching for "postid".

It's up to you but I would strongly suggest you to do those changes directly editing your posts and modifying manually the corresponding title tag.